# How do I obtain classpath of another java project?

Tags: java, plugins, maven, project, classpath

I am writing a maven plugin now and need to obtain the classpath of another java project. I would like to know if it is possible to get the classpath of another java project from my current java project?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Getting "the classpath of another java project" has no meaning in Maven. Describe what you actually want to do (ie, *what* information you need, and *what* you plan to do with it).

Answer (score 1):

if "another java project" means "the project that declears your plugin", here is my answer :

you need to create new classloader from plugin :

```
List classpathElements = project.getCompileClasspathElements();
classpathElements.add( project.getBuild().getOutputDirectory() );
classpathElements.add( project.getBuild().getTestOutputDirectory() );
URL urls[] = new URL[classpathElements.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i < classpathElements.size(); ++i ) {
  urls[i] = new File( (String) classpathElements.get( i ) ).toURL();
}
return new URLClassLoader( urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
```

with new classloader, you can do something (loading class, reflection, generating code) with project's classes

[hibernate3-maven-plugin](https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/tags/maven-hibernate3-2.2/hibernate3-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/hibernate3/HibernateExporterMojo.java) use the same trick to generate mapping from project's annotated classes